# Creating rules programmatically in WFF

Tags: workflow-foundation, rules, rule-engine

i need to create rule in Windows Workflow Foundation without using RuleSet editor. Maybe i didnt search enough on google but i cant find any examle of this.

Example of desired result:

```
var ra = new List<RuleAction>();
ra.Add(new RuleAction());
var rc = new RuleCondition();

var rule = new Rule("test", rc, ra, null);
```

Thanks ahead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this blog-post answers your question: [Programmatically Create Windows Workflow Rules](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/skaufman/archive/2006/05/15/programmatically-create-windows-workflow-rules.aspx)