# Programatically create a WWF RuleCondition from a string

Tags: c#, workflow-foundation, rule-engine

I'm using the RuleSetDialog to create rules for a validation module and storing the resulting xml in the database.
Is there any way to programatically create rules their conditions based on a code string?

This post gave me some insight:
[Creating rules programmatically in WFF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5350144/creating-rules-programmatically-in-wff)

However I need something a lot simplier like

```
RuleCondition rc = new RuleCondition("this.ErrorsDetected==true", "Console.WriteLine(ERROR_MSG)", "DoNothing()";
```

Is there any way to achieve this?

Thanks in advance
Bruno

Comment: Thought this would be about wrestling/charity name injunctions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can't achieve that without some hacking of WF as described [here](http://beaucrawford.net/post/Hacking-into-the-Windows-Workflow-Rules-Engine.aspx).

Basic idea is to use reflection to get same functionality as with RuleSetDialog